# How do I store data submitted to computed properties in a protocol extension?

Tags: swift, swift2

In the app that I'm currently working on, I try to take advantage of the new protocol extension feature in Swift. The idea is that I have a lot of classes implementing the same protocol. Since all these classes should have the same computed properties, and since the properties should behave identically in de different classes, I thought it would be nice to add the functionality only once.

My code is structured as the following example

```
protocol SomeProtocol { ... }

// There could potentially be unlimited different versions of "SomeClass" that implements "SomeProtocol"
class SomeClass : SomeProtocol { ... }

extension SomeProtocol {
    var computedProperty1: Type? {
        get { getData(SOME_ENUM) }
        set { validateAndSave(newValue, atKey: SOME_ENUM) }
    }
    var computedProperty2: Type? {
        get { getData(SOME_OTHER_ENUM) }
        set { validateAndSave(newValue, atKey: SOME_OTEHR_ENUM) }
    }
    ...

    func getData(atKey: ENUM_TYPE) -> Type? {
        [NEED SOME WAY TO GET THE SAVED DATA AND RETURN IT]
    }
    func validateAndSave(value: Type?, atKey: ENUM_TYPE) {
        [NEED SOME WAY TO SAVE DATA FOR LATER RETURNING]
    }
}

// The properties needs to be visible to the client code like this:
class ClientCode {
    let someClassObject: SomeProtocol = SomeClass()
    someClassObject.computedProperty1 = Type()
    print(someClassObject.computedProperty1)
}
```

(The code above shows signs of storing the data in different dictionaries, which was my first thought)

The problem is that an extension does not support stored properties. But where/how do I store the data submitted to the computed properties then?

I can think of 2 different solutions, but none of them good..

1. I could transform the extension into a class that implements `SomeProtocol` instead, and then make `SomeClass` a subclass of it. That would allow me to save the data in stored properties. But it would also require me to implement all the methods the protocol requires in the new class - and that makes absolutely no sense, since it's the different versions of `SomeClass` that should provide different functionality..
2. I could just drop the entire extension idea, and move all the properties into `SomeProtocol`. But that would require me to implement all the computed properties in all the different versions of `SomeClass` with identical functionality, and the whole point of my extension idea was to avoid writing the same implementation for the same properties over and over again..

Is there some completely easy logical solution that I have overlooked?

... or a nice way to save data in a protocol extension that I do not know about?

... or another way of obtaining the desired functionality?

... or should I just suck it up and use one of my not-so-pretty solutions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Protocol extension? Why?

Sometimes we get so hung up on an idea that we ignore a practical solution  staring right at our face.

**1. Do you have set of computed properties? No, you want stored properties.**

> Since all these classes should have the same computed properties, and
>   since the properties should behave identically in de different
>   classes...

... but later

> The problem is that an extension does not support stored properties.
>   But where/how do I store the data submitted to the computed properties
>   then?

**2. Assuming that it is a set of stored properties that you want, you practically provided the solution yourself! Made one change that will make sense now.**

> I could transform the extension into a class <s>that implements
>   SomeProtocol</s> instead, and then make SomeClass a subclass of it. That
>   would allow me to save the data in stored properties.

You extend the class whenever you want to and *then* confirm its subclasses to `SomeProtocol` to get the features. This is cleaner.

On a side note, Swift's protocols not being able to store properties is by design. Protocols do not have existence in their own right and it doesn't make sense to add stored properties in them.

Comment: If Protocols could store properties that would just about make them classes and since Protocols can be added to a class that is subclassed that would essentially create multiple inheritance. But Swift by design does not support multiple inheritance.

Comment: I see your point, and what's actually also something i considered. The problem is that this "solution" breaks the client code, since the properties (stored or computed) is now only visible to the subclass.

Comment: @zaph, You can have a class confirm to as many protocols as you want. It's not multiple inheritance. A viable alternative to one -- but isn't technically one.

Comment: @MortenHC - I don't understand. Your subclass, for all practical purposes is the parent class too. The question of visibility comes only when you added access modifiers. That too, in Swift, is in the module level.

Comment: @avismara Maybe I'm simply missing something here, but here is a simple conversion of the code based on what i think you suggest: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7680526/StackOverflow.png - As you see, the client code does not have access to the properties

Comment: @avismara you seem to have missed my point. If a protocol essentially becomes a class by adding enough capabilities such as stored properties, computer properties you essentially have multiple inheritance. It seems MortenHC is really wanting multiple inheritance with what we used to call mix-ins.

Comment: Yes. Because the type is `SomeProtocol`. `SomeProtocol` doesn't have property1.

Comment: @zaph. Took a moment for me to see that you were agreeing with me there. ;)

Comment: @avismara Yes, I was agreeing and providing some "color".

Comment: @avismara Exactly! That's the problem. But it has to be SomeProtocol. The point of the protocol is that i know i will always be able to call e.g. someMethod1() or one of all the other things the protocol requires. If I change the type to the superclass, we have just reversed the problem. Now the properties will be visible, but we will not see the methods. Remember a part of the problem is that there could potentially be an unlimited number of classes implementing the protocol methods differently, but using identical properties.

Comment: Um... That's the point of polymorphism, right? If you want to treat it as `SomeProtocol`, you can do it. If you want to treat it as `SomeClass`, you can do that as well! You are just one conditional cast away from the solution!

Comment: Hmm.. I actually haven't thought of casting to solve this problem. I guess that would work. I'll consider it, since it'll require a lot of client code rewriting. But I get what you were trying to tell me now ;) Thanks

Comment: Although you started by argue that I did not need computed properties, but stored (which is not true since i need the computed properties functionality), i think you provided the best answer to solve the problem of saving the values calculated by the computed properties. I did nok think about casting as the superclass, which makes my second solution (with the small modification regarding the protocol) a - like you said - pretty clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question correctly to work around the fact that protocol extensions don't support stored properties you could extend NSObject and use the objective C runtime to store your properties.

```
import ObjectiveC

private var AssociationKey: UInt8 = 0

class YourStoredObject {
  // Whatever object your are persisting
}

extension NSObject {
  var yourStoredObject: (YourStoredObject)! {
    get {
      return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey) as? YourStoredObject
    }
    set(newValue) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
  }
}

protocol YourProtocol {
  var yourStoredObject: YourStoredObject! { get set }
}

extension YourProtocol {

  func customYourStoredObjectGetter() -> YourStoredObject {
    return yourStoredObject
  }

}

extension UILabel : YourProtocol {

  func myExtendedFunc() {
    // Get (and print) your object directly
    print(yourStoredObject)
    // Get your object through a protocol custom getter
    print(customYourStoredObjectGetter())

    // Set your object
    yourStoredObject = YourStoredObject()
  }
}
```

I'm not saying this is the best solution but this is the only solution I can think of. I'm also looking for nicer Swift alternatives but still have not found any.

Comment: I agree with you, the solutions are not so clean so far, Swift is not prepared for this kind of behavior through extension protocols yet!!, I hope it come very soon.

Comment: Given the error saying that stored properties are not supported on protocol extensions I'm hoping it gets implemented on subsequent versions since it is a very useful missing feature of Swift.

Comment: I agree this solution would work... but adding a property to every single NSObject seems like a serious overkill. Let's just say if I saw a PR with this change, it would be a reject ;)